# Relationship between local max/min and absolute max/min

Tags: calculus

I'm studying Single Variable Calculus (E7) by James Stewart. In Chapter 4.1, the book does not have a clear statement about the relationship between absolute max/min and local max/min.
This is my proposition:

> Function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$. If $c\in(a, b)$ and $f(c)$ is the absolute max/min, then $f(c)$ must also be a local max/min for any open interval containing c and within domain $[a, b]$.

Is this always true?

Related question:

[Closed Interval Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083457/closed-interval-method)

Comment: Yes that is true.

Comment: @user2923419 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is always true for f continuous that if the absolute max/min value occurs for such $c$ it must be also a local max/min value for any open interval containing $c$ and within $[a,b]$.

It is not true in general for $c=a,b$. Consider for example $y=x$ in $[-1,1]$.

The statement can be easily proved by the definition of local max/min.